# Does every particle/ substance belongs to one of the state of matter?

Tags: states-of-matter, matter

Does every particle/ substance belongs to one of the state of matter? If yes, then which of the state does these belong to?:

1. Light (consider it as matter or wave)
2. Nucleons
3. Electron

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no. An "individual particle" does not, in general, belong to a specific state of matter.

Comment: Is a plasma a state of matter, with protons and electrons? I don't know how exactly you would class it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter